# Haskell class instance branch

Tags: class, haskell, instance

Could someone help me with how I should think in this question?

Given the following datatype

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
```

and the following typeclass

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> Int
```

with the following instances

```
instance Foo Bool where
  foo True = 1
  foo False = 0

instance Foo Int where foo n = n `mod` 5

instance (Foo a, Foo b) => Foo (Tree a b) where
foo (Leaf a) = foo a
foo (Branch a b c) = (foo a + foo b + foo c) `mod` 5

instance Foo a => Foo [a] where
  foo l = (sum (map foo l)) `mod` 5
```

What is the value of

```
foo $ Branch True (Leaf [1::Int,2,3])
                  (Branch False (Leaf [0,3])
                                (Leaf [2,5]))
```

Comment: Use ghci and find out. Otherwise you can use the fact that `(a + b) mod n == (a mod n) + (b mod n) mod n`

Answer (score 2):

I'd think in the following way. Start from the `foo` type

```
foo :: a -> Int
```

OK, so the type if its parameter determines the instance. Then I look at the call:

```
 foo $ Branch True (Leaf [1::Int,2,3])
              (Branch False (Leaf [0,3]) (Leaf [2,5]))
```

What's the type of that `Branch ...`?  It must be some `Tree a b` but for which `a` and `b`? Let's see...

```
Leaf [1::Int,2,3]
```

Ah! the `Leaf` contains a list of `Int`. I now know `a` is `[Int]`. What about `b`?

```
Branch True ....
```

The first argument of `Branch` must be of type `b`, so `True :: b` must hold. Well, this means that `b` is `Bool`.

Summing up, `foo` is being called with a `Tree [Int] Bool` parameter.
This matches with

```
instance (Foo a, Foo b) => Foo (Tree a b) where
```

where `a,b` are as we found. This is also using `Foo a` and `Foo b`... which mean `Foo [Int]` and `Foo Bool`.

```
  foo (Leaf a) = foo a   -- this refers to Foo [Int]
  foo (Branch a b c) = (foo a + foo b + foo c) `mod` 5
                  --    ^-- this to Foo Bool
                  --            ^-- this to Foo (Tree [Int] Bool), recursively
                  --                    ^-- this to Foo (Tree [Int] Bool), recursively
```

Now, what's the instance for `Foo [Int]` and `Foo Bool`?

And so on. I think you can figure out the rest.